# Jerky mouse movement on BorderContainer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

It seem when I trying to drag the bordercontainer to move along x-axis position on mouse down. It appear to move stable but became jerky when I drag a little faster.

Any way to get bordercontainer move with smooth motion?

```
private function mDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gMouseX = event.localX;
    borderCntr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMoveHandler);
}

private function mMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    borderCntr.x = int(event.localX)-gMouseX;
}
```

Comment: You should consider reviewing some of your past questions and selecting answers if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

are you targeting mobile devices?  `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` is quite intensive for mobile devices since it calls many more times faster than the framerate.  it's not optimized nor recommended to use `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` for projects with mobile deployment targets.

instead, create your own moving logic by employing either the `stageX` and `stageY` properties or `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()` functions with an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event.

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't use local coordinates in your `mMoveHandler`, because it's coordinates of mouse inside `borderCntr` - it simply couldn't work as you wish to. Use parent's or top level application's `mouseX` or simply `event.stageX`.

2) Don't add `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` listener to `borderCntr`. When you will make very quick movement and mouse will walk outside `borderCntr`, you simply won't recieve move events anymore. Instead listen to parent or stage or top level application (again), the one that would not loose mouse.